# Sum of groups of records based on a specific value

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

| invoice | description | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | labor | 125.00 |
| 123 | shop materials | 25.00 |
| 124 | bolt | 10.00 |
| 125 | labor | 100.00 |
| 125 | bolt | 10.00 |

Invoice "123" and "125" both have a row with description "labor". I need the sum of cost for all rows with those invoices.

| total |
| --- |
| 260.00 |

I have made many attempts at this, and I have searched ad nauseam. But I'm not even sure how to pose this as a succinct question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is 260? Aggregating `Labor` is 135 and summing everything is 270, not 260.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) total
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(cost) cost
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY invoice
  HAVING SUM(description = 'labor') > 0
) t;
```

Or, with `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(SUM(cost)) OVER () total
FROM tablename
GROUP BY invoice
HAVING SUM(description = 'labor') > 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mAM5_pXA).